# Как с помощью только CSS сделать сдвинутый блок?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Делаю меню. Хотелось бы сделать сдвинутый вправо блок как на картинке блок зелёного цвета, но информации найти не могу. [image: Пример]

Comment: какой блок ? на картинке их 2 , конкретней ставте задачу

Comment: @MoJlo4HuK как блок зелёного цвета.

Comment: `right: -10px;position: absolute;` -> https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/q6dwk8db/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например вот так:

```css
.wrapper{
  padding:20px;
  background:#6e879b;
}
ul{
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
  margin:0 10px 0 0;
  padding:20px 0;
  list-style:none;
  background:#fff;
  border-top-right-radius:10px;
}
li{
  margin:0 -10px 15px 10px;
}
a{
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  padding:10px 20px 10px 10px;
  color:#fff;
  background:#8bc34a;
}
a:after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  right:0;
  border-top:5px solid #3b5220;
  border-right:10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">пункт</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">пункт</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">пункт</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><!--.wrapper-->
```

Answer (score 4):

```
margin-right: -//количество пикселей на которое вам нужно вынести(отрицательный margin);
```

тень можно сделать псевдоклассами :after:before.
Еще вариант дать родителю position:relative; , зеленому блоку position:absolute; и с помощью top/left спозиционировать его так как вам нужно